# Terraform import volumes assigned to instances list

Tags: amazon-web-services, volume, terraform

I have configured a resource for instances list:

```
resource "aws_instance" "masters" {
    count = "${var.masters_count}"
#   count = 2
    ami = "${var.aws_centos_ami}"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    key_name = "${var.aws_key_name}"
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.bastion.id}"]
    associate_public_ip_address = true
    source_dest_check = false
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.eu-west-1b-public.id}"

    availability_zone = "eu-west-1b"

    tags {
            Name = "master-${count.index}"
        }
}
```

Then I attach volumes to that instances:

```
data "aws_ebs_volume" "masters_ebs_volume" {
    count = 2
    filter {
      name   = "attachment.instance-id"
      values = ["${element(aws_instance.masters.*.id, count.index)}"]
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to import the volumes to terraform. I just try using:

```
terraform import aws_ebs_volume.data[0] vol-1153438514541
terraform import aws_ebs_volume.masters_ebs_volume[0] vol-1153438514541
terraform import aws_ebs_volume.masters[0] vol-1153438514541
terraform import aws_ebs_volume.data vol-1153438514541
terraform import aws_ebs_volume.masters vol-1153438514541
```

But nothing works.. how can I import that volumes?

Comment: Try changing the `data` to a `resource`, then `import`.

Comment: @maffo But I want to attach the volume to the instances. Not just create some volumes

Comment: You cant `import` to a `data` object. `data` objects are used to fetch data about already existing objects. You need to change to the `resource` type, then import. This will add the resource to your terraform state.

Comment: @maffo Thankss, but how can I do a aws_volume list using resource? I try it but I am having the error: `* aws_volume_attachment.ebs_att[0]: instance_id must be a single value, not a list`

Comment: You can only have one volume imported to one resource: `import aws_ebs_volume.data vol-049df61146c4d7901`. You need to find another work around.

Comment: @maffo  this is not my problem. I have create a list of instances, I want to create a volume per instance, and attach it. Then I want to import all the volumes. using data I can create 3 volumes and attach it to the instance. With resource it fails.

Comment: Looking at your answer, I was assuming these drives would be persistent rather than ephemeral.

Comment: Yes sorry, is the solution I found.. else is not possible to remove it all volumes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved adding:

```
root_block_device {
  delete_on_termination = true
}
```

So doesn't matter if the volumes change externally, it destroy.